# How to open an Excel document and read values using Open XML in C#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I would like to be able to open an excel document and loop through the values in the cells using Open XML in C#.

Tried using the below code, but it never gets past the Foreach (Row...).  Also comments state this is for numeric values not Alpha Numeric values.

```
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(Filedirectory, false))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
        SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
        string text;
        foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
        {
            foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                text = c.CellValue.Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you googled this at all?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp. Many of those tools also support reading values from Excel.

Comment: Check this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx

Comment: This was helpful Precious but for some reason it doesn't read the values.  Also there is a comment that it is only for numeric values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A coworker came up with the following solution.

```
            FileInfo uploadedFile = new FileInfo(FileDirectory);
            using (ASC.ExcelPackage.ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ASC.ExcelPackage.ExcelPackage(uploadedFile))
            {
                ASC.ExcelPackage.ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                Int32 currentRow = 1;
                while (worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1) != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value))
                {
                    string value = worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value;

                    currentRow++;
                }
            }
```